# Eliminate database rows based on mod dates

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an issue grabbing data from two tables base on a single field in one of the tables The field does not exist in both tables.

Example:

### Table 1 (call it invoices):

```
invoice     email        customer_name     original_bill    invoice_status
   1       a@g.com        bob                 5.00              P
   2       a@g.com        harry               23.00             P
   3       a@g.com        sally               4.00              P  
   4       b@g.com        loretta             14.00             P  
   5       b@g.com        hamish              74.00             P
```

### Table 2 (customer invoice edits):

```
invoice    email       date_last_modified_timestamp        mod_status           mod_amount
   1      a@g.com             2019-05-01                       A                   3.00
   1      a@g.com             2019-04-01                       D
   3      b@g.com             2019-10-25                       A
```

### What I want

a list of all invioces and their mods but I only wish each invoice to appear once in the list. based on the latest date in Table two.

example:

```
invoice     email        customer_name     original_bill    invoice_status       date_last_modified_timestamp        mod_status           mod_amount
   1       a@g.com        bob                 5.00              P                  2019-05-01                       A                   3.00
   2       a@g.com        harry               23.00             P                                               
   3       a@g.com        sally               4.00              P                  2019-10-25                       A                          
   4       b@g.com        loretta             14.00             P  
   5       b@g.com        hamish              74.00             P
```

How im pulling it now:

```sql
select invoice, email, customer_name, original bill, invoice status, max(date_last_modified_timestamp), mod status, mod_amount

from table one

left join on table1.invoice = table 2.invoice

group by
invoice, email, customer_name, original bill, invoice status, max(date_last_modified_timestamp), mod status, mod_amount
```

I've tried a gazzillion variation to no avail.

### What i get

i do get accurate results, but those results inclues a duplicate row containing each invoice that has been modified. I only want one invoice per row. I want the one that's been modified last. Is this even possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) You need more explanation.  What is changing in the second table?  Is it all the columns at one, only one column, all columns with non-NULL values?  If the last, how are NULL values handled in the main data?  (3) What is `mod_status`?

Comment: Hint: It is possible.

Comment: @gordon: Thank you for the edits. I was having trouble formulating the question. I added a tag to the post stating that this was an access database. As for the details: these two tables are used for an approval log. The user may use it to approve or modify invoices. I didn't want the user modifying live data, so I made a separate database for the edits and a linked table in the live database. The query I am looking for lists all the invoiced available for edit. I would like to leave all invoices available for edit for now regardless of status.

Comment: @JustinEgan . . . Please show the results you want.

Comment: @Gordon I added an example. Does it even make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can join and use a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select i.*, e.*
from invoices i
inner join customer_invoice_edits e
    on  e.invoice = i.invoice
    and e.date_last_modified_timestamp = (
        select max(date_last_modified_timestamp)
        from customer_invoice_edits e1
        where e1.invoice = e.invoice
    )
```

This will give you one record per row in the `invoices` table that has a match in `customer_invoice_edits`, along with the latest corresponding record in `customer_invoice_edits`.

If some invoices have no corresponding record in the dependant table, they will not appear in the resultset. If you do want to see them, then you can use a `left join` instead.

Comment: what am I doing wrong here. all i get is some vague syntax error:
```
SELECT A.invoice, A.ID, A.SEQ, A.CARRIER, A.SHIPPER, A.CONSIGNEE, A.PLANT, A.BILL_AMT, A.PAID_AMT, A.CURRENCY, A.Batch, A.CKNUM, A.Auth_Status, B.modDate, B.modID, B.modInvoice, B.modSeq, B.modPlant, B.modAmt, B.modAuthStatus

FROM Tbl1 A 
LEFT JOIN Tbl2 B 
ON A.ID+A.invoice+A.SEQ = B.modID+B.modInvoice+B.modSeq
AND B.modDate = (select max(modDate) from modLogs C where C.modID+C.modInvoice+C.modSeq = B.modID+B.modInvoice+B.modSeq
```

Comment: It just says "Syntax error in query expression" (im stuck using Access to build the query)

Comment: I narrowed it down. The error only happens when I add "AND B.modDate = (select max(modDate) from modLogs C where C.modID+C.modInvoice+C.modSeq = B.modID+B.modInvoice+B.modSeq"

Comment: @JustinEgan: ms-access syntax is not my strongest skill (your question was not tagged `ms-access` at the time when I posted my answer)... You can try to add parentheses around each condition. Or maybe move that condition with the correlated subquery to the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select 
    invoice, 
    email   
from (
    select 
        invoice, 
        email, 
        mod_status, 
        mod_amount, 
        date_last_modified_timestamp,
        row_number() over (
            partition by invoice, email 
            order by date_last_modified_timestamp desc
        ) rn 
    from table2
) 
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you want this field-by-field.  Here is an example:

```
select i.invoice,
       nz( (select top (1)
            from invoice_edits as ie
            where ie.invoice = i.invoice and ie.email is not null
           ), i.email
          ) as email,
       nz( (select top (1)
            from invoice_edits as ie
            where ie.invoice = i.invoice and ie.mod_amount is not null
           ), i.original_bill
          ) as original_bill,
       . . .
from invoices as i;
```